# Cant get HTML text to appear over the right image

Tags: html, css, text, stylesheet, absolute

Weird one. I'm trying to get a line of HTML text, in this case one that says SHOP BAGS for the homepage of an e-commerce site and the problem is its appearing over the wrong image. I wrapped the image I do want the text to appear in its own div, re-did the CSS but it's still not working right. Stumped trying to figure out why and I don't want to change the absolute positioing and I really shouldn't need to. So can someone take a peek and offer a suggestion to a fix?

http://originalchuck.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute positioned elements are going to the `top` of the next relative positioned element. Reduce absolute position boundaries to the scope of a parent element by making the parent position relative.

```
 .thumbnail a {
     position: relative;
     display: block;     
 }
```

I would apply like above because `.text-content` is positioned within the `a` tag

```css
.thumbnail a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;     
}

span.text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/580x278/333333/" alt="" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>Shop Buckets</span></span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/580x278/333333/" alt="" />
        <span class="text-content"><span>Shop Bags</span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. That seemed to have worked out great.